# Replace blank cells with different values/characters in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a bigdata (>20G) with this format:

```
chr snp beta    sebeta  f.stat  p.value error   warning
1   x1  1       1.1     1.5 
1   x2  2       1.2     1.6      0.1    NA      NA
1   x3  3       1.3     1.7      0.2    NA      NA
1   x4  4       1.4     1.8      0.3    NA      NA
```

For some reasons, some lines the last three cells are blank. For these cases I would replace the blank cells with "1" for `p.value`, "NA", for `error` and "NOT ESTIMABLE" for `warning`. I would like to know how to realize this in BASH such like:

```
chr snp beta    sebeta  f.stat  p.value error   warning
1   x1  1       1.1     1.5      1      NA      NOT ESTIMABLE
1   x2  2       1.2     1.6      0.1    NA      NA
1   x3  3       1.3     1.7      0.2    NA      NA
1   x4  4       1.4     1.8      0.3    NA      NA
```

My platform is Mac OS X 10.9.5 Terminal.

Comment: Yes, fields are fixed and they are tab separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ if (NF==5) print $0, 1, "NA", "NOT ESTIMABLE"; else print }' file
```

If the number of fields is 5, add the columns, otherwise print the line as-is. I have set the output field separator `OFS` to a tab character, so that each column in the output is separated by a tab.

A slightly shorter way of achieving the same output would be like this:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF == 5 { $0 = $0 FS 1 FS "NA" FS "NOT ESTIMABLE" }1' file
```

This adds the extra fields to the line when the field count is 5. The 1 at the end is a common shorthand which causes awk to print each line. This method assumes that each field in the input is separated by a tab character and uses the value of `FS` to separate the other fields.